# d3 js tooltips wont show

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Not sure what I might be doing wrong here but my tool tips do not show. I have a pre existing svg to which I want to append a simple empty rectangle as tool tip (later will add a pie chart to each tool tip) to each path. It shows the change in stroke colour as I mouse over but does not show tool tips.

my code:

```
    var w = 500,
        h = 500;

    var tooltip = d3.select("#level_0")
                   .selectAll("path")
                   .append("svg:svg")
                   .attr("class", "tooltip")
                   .style("opacity", 0)
                   .attr("width", w)
                   .attr("height", h)
                   .append("svg:g");

var main_svg =  d3.select("#level_0")
               .selectAll("path")
               .data(data_clean)

             .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                 .style("stroke-width", "3px")
                 .style("stroke", "#000")
                 tooltip.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar");
                 tooltip.transition()
                .   duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
            });
```

**here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/**

Comment: fiddle? difficult to tell without test for me.

Comment: @JulienLeray, okay creating a fiddle

Comment: @JulienLeray: here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/

Comment: Looks like you're inserting a <div> directly into an SVG? I think you need to look into the foreignObject tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: I append the switsch and forigenObject tag as well, but same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are slecting  all 'tooltips' in your onmouseover event, you need to select only the child tooltip and put the style then append the html, just update your onmousever to be:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                 .style("stroke-width", "3px")
                 .style("stroke", "#000");

    d3.select(this).select('#tooltip')
              .style("opacity", "1")
                  .style("display", "block")
              .append("div")
              .attr("class", "data")
              .html(d.data_clean)
                  .transition()  //Opacity transition when the tooltip appears
                  .duration(500);
```

});

Also add some data to your tooltip div to show up and CSS `position` style

Here is another solution, don't add the tooltip div inside your path just add it to your main div and you can append data to it

```
     .on("mouseout", function () {
    d3.select(this)
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("stroke", "#888888");

     tooltip.selectAll('.data').remove();
})



.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                 .style("stroke-width", "3px")
                 .style("stroke", "#000");

     tooltip.  style("opacity", "1")
                  .style("display", "block")
              .append("div")
              .attr("class", "data")
              .html(d.data_clean)
                  .transition()  //Opacity transition when the tooltip appears
                  .duration(500);
```

I changed tooltip to be

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#viz")               
           .append("div")
           .attr("id", "tooltip")
           .style("opacity", 0)
           .attr("width", w)
           .attr("height", h);
```

just update your CSS #tooltip to have  `top: 20px; left:20px`   you can also style #tooltip > div to have some style I tried it it worked in your jsfiddle link

Comment: Thankyou fro your answer I updated the code according to your suggestion but it still wont show the tooltips, here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/1/